# How to clone (and restore) a DOM subtree

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to modify a DOM subtree and restore it after a while. How can I save a sub-tree copy aside (to play with the actual subtree)? How can I restore the saved copy afterwards?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, then I think all you'd need to do is:

```
var DomTreeCopy = $('parentElementSelector').clone(true,true);
```

And then to re-attach the `DomTreeCopy` (in place of the original):

```
$('parentElementSelector').replaceWith(DomTreeCopy);
```

Or to add it to the DOM in addition to the original:

```
$(DomTreeCopy).insertAfter($('parentElementSelector'));
```

References:

- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
- [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

Comment: Thanks. Sharing an upvote, not marking as a perfect answer, since cloning won't support CSS styles/event handlers? Am I right, please?

Comment: Did you read the reference material for `clone()`? The first `true, true` arguments passed to the method means that it copies data and events bound to the elements. The first `true` applies to the element cloned, and the second `true` to the children of the cloned element. As long as your stylesheet supports selectors matched by the elements cloned then yes, CSS will apply itself/be applied automatically.

Comment: brilliant, saved me a ton of time managing state of a custom (editable) control.

Answer (score 10):

Using simple JavaScript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('theElement'),
    backupElem = elem.cloneNode(true);
// Your tinkering with the original
elem.parentNode.replaceChild(backupElem, elem);
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pf7TL/)

[MDN - cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode)

[MDN - replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.replaceChild)

<strike>Note that using this method, your event handlers are **not** restored. But you can back them up too, since they're just ordinary functions.</strike>

Turns out, I was wrong about that. The event handlers are preserved since it's the original DOM that you're restoring. If you were copying it and appending it elsewhere, the event handlers wouldn't be copied. [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pf7TL/1/) shows that the event handler remains.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on event handlers?

Comment: @BreakPhreak Looks like I was wrong about that. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$.data()`... method

```
    $.data(document.body, "sortElement", "0"); //set value
    $.data(document.body, "sortElement");        //read value
```

this was you can store all waht you want in a dictionary type - and then reuse it later.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Answer (score 0):

You can store the cloned object somewhere else in the DOM. Modify the DOM which is visible. When you require the actual value you can track it from the place where you have appended.

```
<div id="oldInfo"></div>

$("#youActualDom").clone().appendTo("#oldInfo").hide();
```

Then track the original dom with `$("#oldInfo")`