# CKEDITOR: Undo All DOM changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, ckeditor, reset

I'm using CKEDITOR's Inline toolbar to edit text. The plugin does a lot of DOM changes and I'm fine with that.

What I want to do is to remove all attributes, elements, classes, ids, and everything that CKEDITOR added to my DOM. I can simply find all the changes and remove them individually but I want to know if there is an easier way. Also I want to be able to undo these changes on button click.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702165/how-to-clone-and-restore-a-dom-subtree

Comment: I really would prefer using a cleaner method.

Answer (score 0):

The closest that you can get using the API is by calling `editor.destroy();` but I think that some people stated that it still leaves some artifacts in inline editing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into `getData` and `setData` methods [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_savedata)

What you can do is to save the old state in a variable and then you can replace it using the `setData` method

```
var old = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
$('#undo').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(old);
});
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qdndP/148/)**